# How to remove background colour from a div

Tags: html, css

(Problem solved, I will accept my answer in 2 days when the system allows me to).

[image]

I have a background applied to all of my `div` elements within my `.main` class. However, I would not like this background to be applied to the `.options` `div`. How can I do this?
The arrows are pointing to the background I am referring to in the image.

I have tried to add `background-color: transparent !important` in the `.options` CSS element, but that didn't fix it and nothing happened.

(Please view the code snippet in the full page as it shows the problem better)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/d7W4Xn1.jpg)
    no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn-select {
  background-color: #008cba;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.main div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.big {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.btn-game {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.restart {
  width: 70px;
}

.new-game {
  width: 200px;
}

.score-div {
  display: none;
}

.num {
  display: none;
}

.options {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.option {
  background-color: cyan !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <body>
    <main class="text-justify text-center main">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="big"><span>All Flags</span></h1>
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="score">Score: <span></span>/251</h2>
        </div>
        <h2 class="num">Question: <span></span></h2>
        <div class="flag-img">
          <img src="https://flagcdn.com/h240/jm.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="container options">
          <div class="text-justify text-center">
            <p class="option">Scotland</p>
            <p class="option">Guyana</p>
            <p class="option">Jamaica</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="restart()" class="btn-game restart">Restart</button>
        <button onclick="newGame()" class="btn-game new-game">
          Try a different gamemode
        </button>
        <div class="score-div">
          <h3 class="correct">Correct Answers: <span></span>/251</h3>
          <button onclick="restart()" class="btn-game restart">Restart</button>
          <button onclick="newGame()" class="btn-game new-game">
            Try a different gamemode
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="all.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: I cannot see any background color applied with your given code. Can you check?

Comment: It's not clear what you want: You have a div container with an `.options` class that **has** transparent background, and you have three `p` tag with a class `.option` which has a background-color defined. Everything works as defined. What should be different?

Comment: @Johannes I would like to remove the white background behind the options highlighted in cyan.

Comment: In the snippet above *everything* behind/around the cyan elements is white, and the `options`container is transparent. Obviously your snippet differs from your real code... So the problem isn't  reproducible with the code you gave.

Comment: @Johannes If you view the snippet in the full page, you will see that there is a background with 100% opacity behind the options. I would like to get rid of this and only have the 50% opacity background which is already there.

Comment: FYI: The background image of `body` doesn't load ("can't be loaded"), so it's impossible to see what you mean.

Comment: @Johannes sorry about that, the image loaded for me. I have changed it now to the colour black so that you can see the error more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by doing the the following:

- Adding
  `.main div:not(.options) { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) !important; }` to my CSS
- Adding the `.options` class to the child `div` which originally was just centering the text.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/d7W4Xn1.jpg)
    no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn-select {
  background-color: #008cba;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.main div {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.main div:not(.options) {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) !important;
}

.big {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.btn-game {
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.restart {
  width: 70px;
}

.new-game {
  width: 200px;
}

.score-div {
  display: none;
}

.num {
  display: none;
}

.options {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.option {
  background-color: cyan !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <body>
    <main class="text-justify text-center main">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="big"><span>All Flags</span></h1>
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="score">Score: <span></span>/251</h2>
        </div>
        <h2 class="num">Question: <span></span></h2>
        <div class="flag-img">
          <img src="https://flagcdn.com/h240/jm.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="container options">
          <div class="text-justify text-center options">
            <p class="bg-none option">Scotland</p>
            <p class="option">Guyana</p>
            <p class="bg-none option">Jamaica</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="restart()" class="btn-game restart">Restart</button>
        <button onclick="newGame()" class="btn-game new-game">
          Try a different gamemode
        </button>
        <div class="score-div">
          <h3 class="correct">Correct Answers: <span></span>/251</h3>
          <button onclick="restart()" class="btn-game restart">Restart</button>
          <button onclick="newGame()" class="btn-game new-game">
            Try a different gamemode
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="all.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have applied `background-color: transparent !important;` to `.options` in your code,
and `background-color: cyan !important;` to `.options`
So, due to which CSS is applying `cyan` to the option not the options contianer

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: url(http://ndquiz.epizy.com/flags/img/worldPersonalProject.png)
    no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn-select {
  background-color: #008cba;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

.main div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.big {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.btn-game {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.restart {
  width: 70px;
}

.new-game {
  width: 200px;
}

.score-div {
  display: none;
}

.num {
  display: none;
}

.options {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
background-color: cyan !important;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.option {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <body>
    <main class="text-justify text-center main">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="big"><span>All Flags</span></h1>
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="score">Score: <span></span>/251</h2>
        </div>
        <h2 class="num">Question: <span></span></h2>
        <div class="flag-img">
          <img src="https://flagcdn.com/h240/jm.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="container options">
          <div class="text-justify text-center">
            <p class="option">Scotland</p>
            <p class="option">Guyana</p>
            <p class="option">Jamaica</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button onclick="restart()" class="btn-game restart">Restart</button>
        <button onclick="newGame()" class="btn-game new-game">
          Try a different gamemode
        </button>
        <div class="score-div">
          <h3 class="correct">Correct Answers: <span></span>/251</h3>
          <button onclick="restart()" class="btn-game restart">Restart</button>
          <button onclick="newGame()" class="btn-game new-game">
            Try a different gamemode
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="all.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Like in this snippet

> More about [`!important`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp)

Comment: The .option and .options classes are different, and this does not fix my problem as the 100% opacity white background behind the options is still there.

Comment: Sorry a silly mistake on my end,See the Edited answer